# ember: dynamic language in templates. use LanguageController?

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember app written in pre 1.0 ember. I want to re-write the app in ember 2.0.

In the old codebase I have an LanguageController that have english defintions of all langauge strings, and I have an ajax call to populate the language controller with strings from another language. I then have that controller available as a global variable available in all templates. An ember 2.0 template may look like this:

```
<label id="lblHomeNextAppointment">{{EEA.lang.home_next_appointment}}</label>
    <div class="appointment">
        {{model.nextAppointment.formattedDate}}
        {{model.nextAppointment.title}}
    </div>
```

I want to put the dynamic language string where it says `EEA.lang.home_next_appointment`.

How to structure controllers etc. to achieve this? Maybe use a service? Whats the fundamental difference between a controller and a service?

The old (pre 1.0) controller looks like this:

```
EEA.LanguageController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    // Default values for language strings
    "header_progress": 'Progress',
    "header_planned": 'Planned',
    "home_next_appointment": "Next Appointment",
...
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        EEA.lang = this;  // Shorter to write EEA.lang, than EEA.router.languageController
    },
...
```

Comment: If you want to move forward to modern versions of ember, consider using ember-cli and addons. There is a good one for translations https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

Answer (score 2):

You should use library for internationalization. [Ember-I18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) does exactly what are you looking for.

In your template you can use `{{t}}` helper:

```
<label id="lblHomeNextAppointment">{{t 'lang.home_next_appointment'}}</label>
```

You just need [file with translations](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Defining-Translations):

```
export default {
  lang: {
    'home_next_appointment': 'whatever'
  }
};
```

> I have an ajax call to populate the language controller with strings
>   from another language.

With Ember-I18n you can [define translations at runtime](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Defining-Translations#defining-translations-at-runtime).

For example, you could setup dynamic loading of required translations in `beforeModel()` hook of `application` route:

```
i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

beforeModel() {
    let lang = $.cookie('user-lang');
    if (!lang) {
      lang = 'pl';
    }

    this.set('lang', lang);

    Ember.$.getJSON('/translations/' + lang + '.json', (json) => {
      this.get('i18n').addTranslations(lang, json);
    });
},
```

Of course, with approach above you need to have `.json` translation files under public `translations` URL path.

Answer (score 2):

There are few approaches for solving this, however in my opinion it's best to use `Ember.Service()` for this, for instance by creating `Translator` service (See [Service Guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/services/)). I would reason this using following arguments:

- You could detach `Translator` service from app and use it in other one
- You could connect such service on-demand when needed (components, controllers, other services etc.)
- You could eagerly load such service globally by using [object initializer](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#toc_initializers) if needed
- While you still could do it, coupling `Route` with controller would not requirement anymore

In this scenario you could do something like this:

Translator service:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  lang: 't1', // For reference
  current: {},
  init: function() {
    this.current = this.translations[this.lang];
  },
  changeLanguage: function(lang) {
    this.set('lang', lang);
    this.set('current', this.translations[lang]);
  },
  translations: {
    t1: {a: 'T1:A', b: 'T1:B'},
    t2: {a: 'T2:A', b: 'T2:B'}
  }
});
```

Injecting in controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  translator: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

And usage in template:

```
<p>{{translator.current.a}}</p>
```

See [full gist](https://gist.github.com/exlee/9d09fa8c3032713eae3b) or [live example](http://ember-twiddle.com/9d09fa8c3032713eae3b).

Obviously, one could do better, for instance by splitting into `Translator` (for setup/configuration) and `Dictionary` (for exposing selected language translations), so that template use would be something like `{{Dictionary.index.greeting}}`, but it shows Service-based approach to the problem.